# Symfony 2 Querying Doctrine-mapped objects

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am experiencing an issue when querying for information across objects in my controller. Please let me know if I need to expand on the information provided (I changed the names of the objects to be more clear outside of context).

I have a oneToOne Bidirectional Mapping across two entities that are in separate bundles.

Object 1:

```
oneToOne:
  person:
    targetEntity: Program\PersonBundle\Entity\Person
    fetch: EAGER 
    inversedBy: group
    joinColumn:
      name: id
      referencedColumnName: id
```

Object 2:

```
oneToOne:
  group:
    targetEntity: Program\GroupBundle\Entity\Group
    mappedBy: person
    fetch: EAGER
```

I have the appropriate variables in each of the Entity.php files for each object. My question is regarding accessing this information in my controller. When I try to access information across the bundles, it doesn't grab it on the first call. However, when I call it again, it grabs the information properly. Does anyone know why this is? Isn't 'fetch: EAGER' supposed to solve that issue?

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$personsRepository =  $em->getRepository("PersonBundle:Person");

foreach($persons as $person)
{
     $person->getGroup()->getName(); // This doesn't return anything
     $person->getGroup()->getName(); // This returns the group name....
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow, strange! Looks like a bug to me. Are your vendors up-to-date? See [my blog post about updating](http://www.greg0ire.fr/wordpress/2011/11/).